# How to build a kik bot?

Tags: api, chatbot, kik

Are there any apis or sdk available for creating a 1:1 conversation bot for kik messenger?

I want to find a way with the help of which I can send and receive messages from kik.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://dev.kik.com/ should let you create your bot and use the APIs

Answer (score 0):

BotMill.io (https://github.com/BotMill/kik-botmill) is a Java library for creating ChatBots on Kik. You can check it out and see if it'll work for you.